# Is there any risk in storing user credentials in scan to email setup?

Tags: email, printer, multi-function-printer

A company I work with is getting a new printer, and wants to set up scan to email. The printer company wants a single reply address, and the user's password for that address. Is there any risk involved in doing that? Since there's no generic addresses for the company, someone's Google workspace username and password would be required. The thought gives me the willies. Am I overreacting?

Comment: Does it have to be the employee's *main* Google GMail? One can have multiple email addresses, and through various providers, such as mail.com. Why not create one for company email purposes *only*?

Comment: "someone's Google workspace username and password would be required." - It doesn't have to be an actual person, it can be Mr. Scanner, I assume as an Administrator you have the capability to do that.